# I lost my Parrot OS dual OS after installing Windows 11 update yesterday

Tags: dual-boot, parrotsec

I lost my Parrot os after installing windows 11 update. Before  my laptop boot successfully into Parrot OS. My laptop boot mode is UEFI.

Is there anyway to recover my Parrot os?

[image: Parrot OS installed on 68.36GB partition before]

**Parrot OS installed on 68.36GB partition**
[image]
**above images shows details of disk from USB live boot**

Comment: Is it not shown as boot option with UEFI boot menu? Same key you used to boot live installer flash drive? What brand/model system? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &          
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Go to BIOS and choose a different EFI loader.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  I can not choose different EFI. there is no option.

Comment: Boot from LiveCD/LiveUSB/whatever `man efibootmgr`/ google: efibootmgr. Alternatively you could use EasyUEFI/DiskGenius Free for Windows.

Comment: @oldfred, I have installed ubuntu in my laptop and I can see that Parrot OS folders/files still exist. But I can not use it. I have checked with boot-repair and here is link:https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/k7pKjw6bky/. My laptop brand/model is : Acer Aspire A315-58-58RJ.

Comment: Acer typically requires you to set "trust" inside UEFI. Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Acer Aspire A315-53-386P remove RAID from drive
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oldfred, Trust settings in step 35 http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot is worked and I was able to boot from my Parrot OS. Thank you

@ArtemS.Tashkinov, Thank you for suggesting choose a different EFI loader.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on figuring out the problem yourself. However, please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.